# Ironbarcode.dll : System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net

i use Ironbarcode to read barcodes on an image,
but  i always get the exception message:

> System.MissingMethodException   HResult=0x80131513   Message=Method
>   not found: 'System.Collections.IEnumerator
>   PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPages.GetEnumerator()'。   Source=IronBarCode

I never use Pdfsharp in this project and can't figure out why i got this message!
Could anyone help me?

```
using ironbarcode;

BarcodeResult result = BarcodeReader.QuicklyReadOneBarcode(@"barcode_testing1.jpg");
Console.WriteLine($"Barcoe Text: {result.Value}");
```

Comment: please share your whole class codes

Comment: Based on its description, this library does contain code to edit PDF. It is not an open source library, so in general you can only ask its vendor to assist, https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/ They have a support button on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the PDFsharp version issue.

try with below version

package id="PDFsharp" version="1.32.3057.0" targetFramework="net472"

For beginners:
add the above above line in package.json.
if you are using VS then right click on solution -> click on Restore NuGet Packages.